# Safe and best way to monkey patch a rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have tried, seriously. Many questions out there but many developers say "It dont work for me"; I'm one of them -- said to say.

I was reading up on the best way to monkey-patch a rails gem. I've found [few](https://lrajeshmanjunath.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/monkey-patching-rails-gems-customizing/) but decided to use [this method](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/).

I want to monkey-patch the [xeroizer gem](https://github.com/waynerobinson/xeroizer) but rather the [invoice.rb model](https://github.com/waynerobinson/xeroizer/blob/master/lib/xeroizer/models/invoice.rb).

```
# lib/xeroizer/invoice/invoice_url.rb

module Xeroizer
  module Invoice
    module InvoiceUrl
      def invoice_url(id)
        @application.http_get(@application.client, "#{url}/#{CGI.escape(id)}/OnlineInvoice")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Going with the "this method" link, I assume this should work, but it dosent.

**Controller:**

```
include Xeroizer::Invoice::InvoiceUrl
# Invoice.include Xeroizer::Invoice::InvoiceUrl

def some_method
  # @xero is in a private method. It's here for short demonstration
  @xero = Xeroizer::PrivateApplication.new("MY_CONSUMER_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY", "#{Rails.root}/privatekey.pem")
  Rails.logger = @xero.Invoice.invoice_url("ad61ea97-b9e9-4a1e-b754-7c19e62f8cd7")
end
```

> undefined method `invoice_url' for Xeroizer::Record::InvoiceModel

How do you add custom methods to a rails gem's class?

Comment: could you try putting your code as an initializer

Comment: @Alfie I think I've tried with `Xeroizer::PrivateApplication.class_eval ...` but that never worked. Maybe I havent done it correctly.

Comment: I do not see any attempt to monkey-patch anything. Would you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @mudasobwa It's my first ever attempt of "monkey-patching" I thought it meant add a custom method to a gem? No?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to monkey-patch `Xeroizer::Record::InvoiceModel` with `Xeroizer::Invoice::InvoiceUrl`, you might just do the following *right after the first mention of `Xeroizer::Record::InvoiceModel`* (to make Rails to autoload it):

```
Xeroizer::Record::InvoiceModel.prepend Xeroizer::Invoice::InvoiceUrl
```

This will override original `invoice_url` method. The original one still might be called from a prepended using `super`.

Comment: `invoice_url` is a custom method, it's not in the gem. I want to add a custom method (`invoice_url`) to the `InvoiceModel`.

Comment: Ok. I now got `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`. Is my module correct? I have `invoice_url(id)` it expects one argument when it says expected 0. Why?

Comment: “I now got wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)”—I am not a fortuneteller. Please share the stacktrace. Also, please make sure that the original `Xeroizer::Record::InvoiceModel` does not have a method named `invoice_url`. If it does, you might fix the problem by adding default to the parameter: `def invoice_url(id = nil)`.

Comment: Oh!!!!!! I should have used `puts` instead of `Rails.logger` It works OMG! it works!!! Thanks!!!!!